# I want to make a string in JS by concatenating two strings together

Tags: javascript, html, string, concatenation, percentage

The first string has percentage symbol (`'%'`) at last and the second string has letters `"fan ..."` in the beginning. But after concatenating, it is showing some weird symbol instead of `"............ %fan .........."`

```
var abc = document.getElementById("myInput").value;  ("fan" will be stored in abc)
$value = "WHERE Product_ID LIKE '%" + abc + " %' OR Product_Name LIKE '%" + abc + "%' OR Description LIKE '%" + abc + "%' OR MRP LIKE '%"+abc+"%' OR Net_Amount LIKE '%"+abc+"%' OR Category LIKE '%"+abc+"%' OR Tags LIKE '%"+abc+"%'";
```

Output:

```
"WHERE Product_ID LIKE '�rt %' OR Product_Name LIKE '�rt%' OR Description LIKE '�rt%' OR MRP LIKE '�rt%' OR Net_Amount LIKE '�rt%' OR Category LIKE '�rt%' OR Tags LIKE '�rt%'"
```

I tried replacing `'%'` by `'\%'` but still it is not working.

Comment: How do you output that?

Comment: This is not reproducible without knowing how you get your output string. Your code works for me when logging in the console and/or appending the text to an HtmlElement, with/without passing to `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 0):

YJudging from what you have posted, you are trying to build a query by concatenating different parts. Your string seems fine but the value that you get from abc, which you collect from the input, has a character that is not being interpreted by your text editor or whatever interface you are using to display the result. What you have there is the Replacement character, basically, it says I found this character and I do not know what to do with it, so I will show  � it instead to let you know that something went wrong here. Try to check your editor configuration or keyboard or the fonts you are using with your app or your language settings.

You can find more on this link:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)

Answer (score -2):

Try concatenating an empty string onto the end.

```
var abc = document.getElementById("myInput").value + "";

$value = "WHERE Product_ID LIKE '%" + abc + " %' OR Product_Name LIKE '%" + abc + "%' OR Description LIKE '%" + abc + "%' OR MRP LIKE '%"+abc+"%' OR Net_Amount LIKE '%"+abc+"%' OR Category LIKE '%"+abc+"%' OR Tags LIKE '%"+abc+"%'"
```

Comment: Wondering why appending an empty string to a string would make a difference!